# Prime Factor Implementation

Tags: python

Below I have attached my code for prime factorization and it works. I was just wondering if there is any way I could make the output clearer. I add the prime factors to a list but the final list at the end of the recursion contains a list of lists but I want just a list with numbers.

```
def prime_factor(n):
    list = [] 
    if prime(n)==1:
        list.append(n)
        return list
    else:
        for i in range(2,n):
            if n %i ==0:
                a =prime_factor(i)
                b = prime_factor(n/i)
                list.extend(a)
                list.extend(b)
                return list

def prime(n):
    if n ==2 or n==3:
        return 1
    if n==1:
        return 0
    for i in range(2,n):
        if n%i ==0:
            return 0
            break
        if i ==n-1:
            return 1
            break
```

Comment: 2 and 3 are not the only prime numbers.

Comment: What does `prime(5*7)` give you?

Comment: need to edit prime method

Comment: Use `extend` instead of `append`. And take some more possible prime numbers into account.

Comment: It doesn't work. Try factorizing 121.

Comment: I updated my code. I believe it works now.

Comment: Quick question: When I factor 6, why do I get [2,3], instead of [2,3,2,3]? Because 6 is divisible by both 2 and 3 I am surprised I get just [2,3]

Comment: Why does the for loop automatically stop at 2 when I evaluate prime_fact(6)?

Comment: I see the return statement automatically exits out of loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get prime factors in much easier:

```
def factorize(n):
    factors = []

    p = 2
    while True:
        while(n % p == 0 and n > 0): #while we can divide by smaller number, do so
            factors.append(p)
            n = n / p
        p += 1  #p is not necessary prime, but n%p == 0 only for prime numbers
        if p > n / p:
            break
    if n > 1:
        factors.append(n)
    return factors

print factorize(32*9*11*13*13)
```

prints

[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 11, 13, 13]

Your solution could be improved as:

```
def prime_factor(n):
    list = [] 
    if n==1:
        return [1] #or []?
    else:
        for i in range(2,n+1): #additional improvement could be made here
            if n %i ==0:
                b = prime_factor(n/i)
                list.append(i) #i is always prime in here, you return once first i is found
                list.extend(b)
                return list
```

(Your `def prime(n):` confused me, it is not necessary)

Comment: I wanted to practice recursion so I used a recursive method

Comment: OK, but performance of recursive method is slower. Try factoring 100000000 or 10000000000

Comment: Is there an easy way to calculate the complexity? I'm assuming it T(n) = n*T(n/i)

Comment: In the worse case (when n is prime) you need N (or sqrt(N)) tests, so complexity is O(N)

Comment: Also list is a built-in type, so it is better not to use it as a variable (otherwise list((1,2,3)) won't work)